# Considering the Digital Line Topology from the set of integers, prove that there exists a singleton set that is not closed.

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

The digital line topology is

B(n) = {n} when n is odd

B(n) = {n-1, n, n+1} when n is even.

I've figured out how to prove that the topology is not Hausdorff, but was wondering if there was a way to prove that there is a singleton set in the digital line topology that is not open.

Right now I have that if n is even then the set {n} is not closed
since it does not have a complement in T that is open. Is this reasoning sufficient, or am I missing something?

Comment: Hey, your title asks for an example of a point that's not closed, but the body of your question asks for a point that's not open.  I assume the question in the title is correct?  The sets $B(n)$ are a basis for your topology, right?

Comment: Actually I think it's the odd points that aren't closed, not the even ones.

Comment: $n$ odd implies $\{n\}$ open and not closed, $n$ even implies $\{n\}$ closed but not open.  In fact, the digital line is connected. It's meant (by some) to be a pixelised version of the reals, so it'd better be..

Answer (score 1):

Assume shown that the collection $B(n)$ as described is a basis, and further assume $n$ is odd.  We show that $\lbrace n \rbrace$ is not closed, by showing that its complement is not open.

If its complement $U$ were open, then $n-1$ would be in $U$ and there would be a basis element $B$ containing $n-1$ in $U$.  But since $n$ is odd, we have that $n-1$ is even and thus every basis element $B$ containing $n-1$ contains the elements $n-2$ and $n$.  In particular we have that $n \in B$.  But $B \subset U = \lbrace n \rbrace^c$ was assumed to be disjoint from $\lbrace n \rbrace$, a contradiction.